# Issue with media9 package

Tags: beamer, pdftex, media9

I am having an issue with the media9 package. The following MWE is not working

```
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
\includemedia{}{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-29AZf-NkU}
\end{document}
```

but giving an error

```
<argument> \text_lowercase:n
                             {\filename@ext }
l.6 ...ttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-29AZf-NkU}
```

Same occurs when using u3d files.

Here is listfiles' output

```
*File List*
  beamer.cls    2020/07/22 v3.59 A class for typesetting presentations
beamerbasemodes.sty
etoolbox.sty    2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasedecode.sty
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
beamerbaseoptions.sty
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
graphicx.sty    2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
hyperref.sty    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend.sty    2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty
beamerbasecompatibility.sty
beamerbasefont.sty
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2020/01/31
scrlfile.sty    2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
beamerbasetranslator.sty
translator.sty    2020-08-03 v1.12c Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
beamerbasemisc.sty
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty
beamerbaseoverlay.sty
beamerbasetitle.sty
beamerbasesection.sty
beamerbaseframe.sty
beamerbaseverbatim.sty
beamerbaseframesize.sty
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty
beamerbasecolor.sty
beamerbasenotes.sty
beamerbasetoc.sty
beamerbasetemplates.sty
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
beamerbaseboxes.sty
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty
beamerbasetheorems.sty
 amsmath.sty    2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2020/05/29 v2.20.6
beamerbasethemes.sty
beamerthemedefault.sty
beamerfontthemedefault.sty
beamercolorthemedefault.sty
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty
beamerouterthemedefault.sty
  media9.sty    2020/07/08 v1.12 acrobat-9/X compatible media
   expl3.sty    2019-11-07 L3 programming layer (loader)
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2019-04-06 L3 backend support: PDF mode
l3keys2e.sty    2019-10-11 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
  xparse.sty    2019-10-11 L3 Experimental document command parser
 pdfbase.sty    2020/07/08 v0.43 driver independent access to low-level PDF fea
tures
 ocgbase.sty    2019/11/04 v0.17 support package for ocgx2.sty
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
 nameref.sty    2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
       a.out
       a.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict
 ***********
```

Comment: update your system, your media9 package is quite new, but your expl3 is older.

Comment: Agreed, but upgrading to 2020-08-07 had no effect, same error.

Comment: your document compiles fine for me. Did you update the latex formats?

Comment: Upgrading the koma-script package worked! - so UlrikeFischer's suugestions were helpful. Shall I provide that as an answer to my question?

Comment: koma is quite unrelated, updating it doesn't affect expl3 commands, unless the update triggered a format creation.